# Attached Behaviors in Windows Store Apps with MVVM Light

Tags: mvvm, windows-8, mvvm-light, datatemplate, attachedbehaviors

I've been trying to use Attached Behaviors in a simple Windows Store App using the MVVM Light framework. Since we can't use System.Windows.Interactivity, as in Windows Phone, I've been using both [Windows.UI.Interactivity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Windows.UI.Interactivity) and [WinRtBehaviors](https://nuget.org/packages/WinRtBehaviors) lybraries. They work well but the problem is that **I can't declare an attached behavior inside a data template**.

What I really want is to attach a command to any item in a GridView, so that I can pass the item id as the parameter. Since that attached behavior doesen't work, the only solution I found consists on using the "SelectionChanged" event of the GridView and pass the SelectedItem as the parameter to a property in the ViewModel:

```
    <GridView Grid.Row="1"
              x:Name="itemGridView"
              AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
              AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
              TabIndex="1"
              Padding="116,136,116,46"
              ItemsSource="{Binding GeoTopArtists.topartists.artist}"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedArtist, Mode=TwoWay}"
              IsSwipeEnabled="False"
              IsItemClickEnabled="False">

        <WinRtBehaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Win8nl_Behavior:EventToCommandBehavior Event="SelectionChanged" Command="SelectArtistCommand" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedArtist.mbid}"/>
        </WinRtBehaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250">
                    <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <Image Source="{Binding image[4].text}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding url}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

It would be very nice doing something like that (where there's no need to have a *SelectedArtist* property in the ViewModel)

```
    <GridView Grid.Row="1"
              x:Name="itemGridView"
              AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
              AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
              TabIndex="1"
              Padding="116,136,116,46"
              ItemsSource="{Binding GeoTopArtists.topartists.artist}"
              SelectionMode="None"
              IsSwipeEnabled="False"
              IsItemClickEnabled="False">

        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250">
                    <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <Image Source="{Binding image[4].text}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding url}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>
                    </StackPanel>

        <WinRtBehaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Win8nl_Behavior:EventToCommandBehavior Event="Tapped" Command="SelectArtistCommand" CommandParameter="{Binding Artist.mbid}"/>
        </WinRtBehaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIr8nL3OgwA) may help you out. The dependency property is defined and hooked to a command in view model. So whenever there is interaction in view, the selected item can be sent as commanding parameter which is clearly demonstrated in this video.